# 'Embedded nul in string' error with fread and sed.exe

Tags: fread

I have several huge text files(above 7G each), which were preprocessed with

```
sed.exe 's/\\0//g'
```

to clear all null in the string.

However, `fread()` still complains about 'Embedded null in string' error. Any idea to make sure that all null are cleaned in the files?